# set end Date after select start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

[***JSFIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/ow0gsnvs/)

How can I set end date which must be 1 day after than start date?

```
$("#beginDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    onClose: function (selectedDate, instance) {
        if (selectedDate != '') {
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);
            console.log(selectedDate, date);
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update one line in your code `onclose` event of `beginDatePicker`
use this line

```
var minDate2 = new Date(selectedDate);
minDate2.setDate(minDate2.getDate() + 1);
$("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate2);
```

instead of

```
$("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow0gsnvs/4/)

Comment: @George, sorry for the delay, have updated code with your fiddle, have a look and do let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

For example, in this sample code, `startDatePicker` is selected as 2014-3-18, change event of `startDatePicker` sets the `minDate` of `endDatePicker` 2014-3-19. It locks the cells before this date. I hope it helps...

```
        $("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: '+2y',
        onSelect: function (date) {

            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var msecsInADay = 86400000;
            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

            $("endDatePicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
            $("endDatePicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", '+2y');

        }
    });

    $("endDatePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a date difference. It will invisible the date.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#beginDate, #endDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            if(this.id == 'beginDate'){
              var dateMin = $('#beginDate').datepicker("getDate");
              var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 1); 
              $('#endDate').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);
              $('#endDate').datepicker('setDate', rMin);                    
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that datepicker i expecting a date datatype.

```
            var date = new Date(selectedDate);
            date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
            console.log(selectedDate, date);
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow0gsnvs/5/)